# Passing data from custom directive to component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-directives

I have a directive that obtains a URL from an element binding, and then performs an axios GET request using that URL.

I loop over the returned data, and I would then like to be able to store the data returned along with my change to it, inside the components data() object - news, however I am not sure if this is possible/how it can be achieved.

```js
directives: {
    init: {
        mounted(el, binding) {
            el.id = binding.value
            Promise
            .all([axios.get(el.id)])
            .then((response) => {
                let data = response[0].data;
                for (var i in data) {
                    data[i].date = new Date(data[i].date);
                }
            });
        },
    }
},
```

The component data I wish to store inside:

```js
data() {
    return {
        news: '',
    }
},
```

And the template:

```html
<div class="section news" ref=“myid” v-init:url="'https://www.myurl.com'" id="newsUrl">
```

Comment: That's not what directives are meant for.
Directives are meant for DOM-operations on an element (like setting focus, colors etc.) and not functionality the way you are trying to apply.
Either create yourself a mixin for that or find another way to reuse your logic (for example if you're using composition api you could just create a pure function handling your logic, that function can then be imported wherever you need it for re-use).
BUT! if you insist on doing it like that you could emit an event from the element and use a handler to store the data emitted from the event.

Comment: I understand @Braks thank you for your response. In this case, the url is being dynamically generated and added to the HTML external from any of my vue code. Given this, I thought a directive was the only way to obtain this value from the html?

Comment: How exactly are you generating and adding that URL?

Comment: In my code the URL is like I have shown in this example. My code is added to a content management system, with some additional javascript, which allows me to pull data from the CMS when the code is run from there. I do a simple string replace on the URL depending on the page a user visits with categories and tags pulled from the CMS.

Comment: Okay so you have an application which "embeds" the Vue App from above, am I understanding that correctly? And afterwards the URL you passed is used to fetch the data necessary for the page from your CMS, right?
Can you not add the URL as a query parameter to your current route or something? That'd make it easy for you check the query params for the current URL you need to fetch your data from the CMS and update it on a router.push :)

Comment: I suppose so yes.... I do something like this:
var category = (get the category from the CMS)
var tag = (get the tag from the CMS)
var html = 'allmyvuehtmlhere'
var link = 'https://myurl.com?cat=' + category + "&tag=" + tag;
html = html.replace('https://myurl.com', link);

With the category and tag values being dynamically pulled from the CMS

Comment: From what you commented you're basically using some vanilla js to setup your Vue app in some context (creating some HTML where the Vue app is supposed to be mounted on etc).
At the end of it are you mounting the Vue app or where do you mount it? 
You might be able to just pass it to the Vue instance / App (depending on if you use Vue 2 or 3) which can use the value when it's mounting without you having to do some replacements or anything.

Comment: Yes. So locally, I use it probably as you would expect - .vue files, import into App.vue, use of cli etc. In the vue file I do 'export default....'. When it goes into the CMS, that is replaced with 'const name' and Vue.createApp(name).mount etc. The .vue file becomes a .js file and there is logic in place to load the js as and when it is required on a page.

Comment: I see what you mean about passing it to the vue instance / app. If that happens to not be possible. Have you an alternative suggestion?

Comment: If you can access the context where Vue.createApp is run you can pass your url as a prop like this `createApp(App, {myProp: "value"}).mount('#app')`.

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to access it where Vue.createApp is run

Comment: Alright, well if you can find a solution to pass it directly into your app use that.
But for now if you wanna use the directive solution you already worked on just emit an event up from the element you're using the directive on.
I did the same right [here](https://github.com/bcakmakoglu/revue-draggable/blob/bd3105f5ed27fb7ab4409a140806e38d492ef81e/src/directive/DraggableDirective.ts#L7).
In my example the directive can be used on either a standard dom element like a <div> or a vue component. Depending on what you're using the directive on, the way you emit the event will be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree the directive seems like the wrong way to go about this.

However, it's technically possible to access the Vue component from the directive through `binding.instance`, so you could set the component's `news` property by:

```js
binding.instance.news = response.data
```

But you don't need `Promise.all` because there's only one URL, so only one `Promise` would be needed. You could just use `axios.get()` directly:

```js
//Promise.all([axios.get(el.id)]).then(([response]) => {/*...*/})
axios.get(el.id).then(response => {/*...*/})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-component-in-directive?file=src/App.vue)

Answer (score 0):

This is my way of achieving the outcome I desired and it seems to work fine, but it is not a direct answer to the question I posted. However it works and so should someone have a similar problem to me this may be a way you could solve it:

Assign a ref in the HTML:

```
<div ref="myDiv" id="https://www.myurl.com">
```

Perform my request on the component mounted method and assign the response data to my component data object (this.news):

```
mounted() {
        Promise
        .resolve(axios.get(this.$refs.myDiv.id))
        .then((response) => (
            this.news = response.data
        ))
    },
```

Then back in the HTML I can loop over the data like so:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in news" :key="index">
   <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
   <p>{{item.description}}</p>
</div>
```